# How to store a JSON response from a loop into a dataframe in python

Tags: python, api, dataframe

I am trying to run an API with multiple id's and I am normalizing the json file and trying it to put into a dataframe. With my current code I am able to get only one response into *jsonfile2*. When I try to print the json response I will get all the response but *response.json()* is not working in my code.

```
for id in ids:
    time.sleep(1)
    url = "https:url/../details/"+str(id)
    querystring = {"API-Token":"Token"}
    headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "111111111111111111111"
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url.format(id=ids), headers=headers, params=querystring)
#    print(response.json())
    jsonfile2 = response.json()
    works_data2 = json_normalize(jsonfile2, record_path='result')
```

*Example of JSON response*

```
{
  "result": {
    "id": "string",
    "startTime": 0,
    "endTime": 0,
    "tags": [
      {
        "context": "context",
      }
    ],
    "Events": [
      {
        "startTime": 0,
        "endTime": 0,
        "entityId": "string",
        "status": "CLOSED",
        "severities": [
          {
            "context": "context",
            "value": 0,
            "unit": "Bit (bit)"
          }
        ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you are overwriting the `jsonfile2` variable during each iteration of your loop. How about appending to a list instead?

```
jsonfile2  = []

for id in ids:
    time.sleep(1)
    url = "https:url/../details/"+str(id)
    querystring = {"API-Token":"Token"}
    headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "111111111111111111111"
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url.format(id=ids), headers=headers, params=querystring)
#    print(response.json())
    jsonfile2.append(response.json())
    works_data2 = json_normalize(jsonfile2, record_path='result')
```

Comment: Thanks @JacobIRR that working and additional I stored the appended data into a dataframe by using the following code  **works_data2 = json_normalize(jsonfile2)**